# What is the equivalent of the command tools in Jenkins scirpted pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

How does Jenkins manage plugins? Do all nodes have a set of plugins installed according to the list specified in the master?

What is the equivalent of declarative pipeline's command `tools` in scripted pipeline? If there isn't one, how do we use the tools like Maven, NodeJS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If there isn't one, how do we use the tools like Maven, NodeJS?

According to the node plugin doc at https://plugins.jenkins.io/nodejs/, you could do the following:

```
nodejs(nodeJSInstallationName: 'Node-name') {
     sh 'npm install'
}
```

Same for the maven plugin:

```
withMaven(maven: 'Jenkins Maven') {
  sh 'mvn install'
}
```